# Sidekiq delay email, undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 with Ruby 2.0 and running redis-server and sidekiq 2.17.7 locally, using `redis-server` and `bundle exec sidekiq` in my app directory. I want to send an email using a sidekiq delay like this:

`UserMailer.delay.signup_notification(@user.id, @user.email, activate_url, @user.activation_token, root_url)`

where the `signup_notification` action inside `UserMailer` is this:

```
def signup_notification(user_id, user_email, activate_url, activation_token, root_url)
  return if Rails.env.test?

  @user = User.find(user_id)
  if @user.email.downcase == user_email.downcase
      @activate_url     = activate_url
      @activation_token = activation_token
      @root_url         = root_url
      mail :to => @user.email, :subject => "Welcome to #{t('product.name')} by AppName"
  else
      logger.warn "[#{self.class.name}##{__method__}]  told to send email to user(id: #{user_id}, email: #{user_email}), but actual user is: #{@user.inspect}"
  end

end
```

I get an error in the sidekiq that says this:

```
WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\n- :signup_notification\n- - 6cI7bbeTKXCEROwf1qxdkE\n  - user@test.com\n  - http://0.0.0.0:3003/activate\n  - 76-hibLYSPlcRiN9BTxt_g\n  - http://0.0.0.0:3003/\n"], "jid"=>"c2413ca2c2597af07eb6146c", "enqueued_at"=>1395351890.0875876, "error_message"=>"undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>"2014-03-20T21:44:51Z", "retry_count"=>6, "retried_at"=>1395353704.7546926}
WARN: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
WARN: /home/jchan/projects/MyRailsProject/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:24:in `signup_notification'
```

Line 24 in `user_mailer.rb` is `if @user.email.downcase == user_email.downcase` from the code above.

I'm sure that `@user.id` and everything else I pass in is not `nil`, and everything works perfectly if I don't use the `.delay` (and append `.deliver` to my `UserMailer.signup_notification` call of course).

It's as if the values are not passed over properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you're doing this as part of a larger transaction and sidekiq isn't seeing the updated database records?

Comment: `User.find` should raise an error when it's not finding the record in the db, so i assume that this part is working. is there any reason why you use a  member (`@user`)? can you change that to a local variable?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom This isn't part of a larger transaction. My action basically consists of the `UserMailer.delay` line. @phoet Right, `User.find should raise an error, but I don't see one. I'm using an instance variable because the view needs to display some info from @user.